# Fix the USB error "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive X"

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, usb-drive, disk

I have a 32GB USB Pen Drive which has gone dead (USB drive unusable, unformattable, and reporting 0 bytes capacity). It is not accessible through any OS. When I insert it into my Windows machine and try to open it, it pops up the following message

> "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive X."

I've tried almost everything, but can't fix it.
What I've tried until now:

> 1. Change Drive Letter and Path - http://www.verbatim.com/index/support.php?cat=14&action=support_questions&pid=5467&aid=165
> 2. Re-installed the USB Controllers in windows
> 3. Tried changing the DisableOnSoftRemove vale in regedit - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2830154
> 4. Tried a number of software utilities for windows that helps in force formatting a pen drive.

Further, I tried using the **Disks** program from the dash as well (in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). It shows up my USB Flash drive when I plug it in, but I can't format it or mount it anyhow.
Here are the screenshots for the same:- 
[image]
[image]
When I Click on the Edit Mount Options, the following Windows pops up:
[image]

Is there any way I can recover my Pen Drive back?

PS:- I do not want the contents, just I want to make my USB drive work again.

Comment: ... It's broken ...

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a copy of Hyrens Boot you might be able to repair it using the partition wizard. Not sure where you can find a copy of it unfortunately. I got a bootable copy from a buddy of mine who mounted it on a USB.

Note: To use Hyrens Boot you have to boot it from BIOS

Comment: sounds complicated and laboring task..

Comment: Then buy a new Pen Drive

Comment: http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/

Comment: i assume u know how to make a boot disk. if not here's a link to a tutorial as well.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQtwIwAWoVChMItJi589nwxgIVESmICh02PgYp&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D3oXmwMIJLoo&ei=ApSwVbSPC5HSoAS2_JjIAg&usg=AFQjCNEGSB3BGgv8IMKuVWqLf4MoxiTb_g&sig2=TX18WzGTCE65xn8KFVQ_Vg

Comment: what is this hirens boot exactly?

Comment: Is there any way to fix it through ubuntu?

Comment: hirens is a great tool. military uses alot. tons of programs on it. you can format drives. boot mini xp. and tons more. as through ubuntu im unsure of that as i usually boot mini xp and format with wizard